# I want to clean the element in a list. If my list contains number 1 ans a stirng "1" i want to keep only one element either integer or sting

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,'1','2','3','4','nag','nag','venkat',5,6,7]
l1 = []
for i in l:
    if (str(i) not in l1) and (i not in l1):
        l1.append(i)
print l1
```

I want to clean my list. My list contains numbers and strings. In the above list l i have both 1 and "1". I want to remove either 1 or "1". I want the output as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "nag", "venkat", 6, 7]`

Comment: what is you question?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed in IDLE that this provides the output you're looking for.  Also, I updated the names of some of your variables to be a little easier to understand.

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,'1','2','3','4','nag','nag','venkat',5,6,7]
output_list = []
for i in my_list:
    try:
        if (str(i) not in output_list) and (int(i) not in output_list):
            output_list.append(i)
    except ValueError:
        if i not in output_list:
            output_list.append(i)
print output_list
```

In Python it's common practice to use variables assuming that they're a certain type and just catch errors, instead of going through the process of checking the type (`int`, `str`, etc) on each one.  Here, inside the `try` statement, I'm assuming the loop variable `i` is either an `int` or a `str` that contains only numbers.  Provided that's the case, this section works fine.

However, we know that the list contains some strings of letters, so the `try` block will throw a `ValueError`.  The `except` block catches that and, knowing that this error will result from an attempt to cast a string of letters as an `int` (when we use `int(i)`), we can now safely assume that the loop variable `i` refers to a string of letters, which we then check against the `output_list` and append if needed.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. I want the code exactly what you have given.

Comment: Can you please tell me where i was wrong? why my code was not given exactly what out i need?

Comment: Yes.  The way you had your code did not check for strings containing numbers, such as `'1'` or `'4'`.  This meant that it was constantly including those strings, which you didn't want.  The changes I made ensure that it checks for such strings and handles them the way you want.  If you found my answer helpful, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way with list comprehensions, you create a new list, but this example only works if you know what you want to remove:

```
l1 = [i for i in l if i != "1" if i != "2" if i != "3" if i != "4"]

#output
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'nag', 'nag', 'venkat', 5, 6, 7]
```

or for example only removing the string "1" it would be

```
l1 = [i for i in l if i != "1"]
```

Maybe it could be implemented in a function and a loop to remove such elements with a single if statement with this way. Not sure, anyway I'd go with coralv's way.